# How does code call function(s) of objects when that/those function(s) is/are undefined in the object definition?

Tags: javascript, html, object, prototype

I have this code for an image

```
var img = {
    id: id++,
    link: m.attr("index"),
    x: m.offsetx(),
    y: m.offsety(),
    width: m.width(),
    height: m.height()
};
```

Now I would like to call a function `img.setCordinates(x,y)` and `img.setDimention(w,h)`, but I dont want to add them to the `img` object as I will have many `img` object and they will be saved and loaded in file. It does not mater what the function do, i'm just wondering how they are implemented?

**I should also mention this, The reason I need to do these function is becouse of this code example problem: (not good)**

```
arr.getById(index).x = 100;
arr.getById(index).y = 200;
```

`.getById()` is a direct prototype of array that loops true arr and look for the id specified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should start a new prototype chain for this:

```
function MyImage(data)
{
    // copy data into this instance
    for (var key in data) {
        this[key] = data[key]; // assume that data is anonymous object
    }
}

MyImage.prototype.setCoordinates = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

MyImage.prototype.setDimensions = function(width, height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}
// etc.
```

Then you can create a new image like this:

```
var img = new MyImage({
    id: id++,
    link: m.attr("index"),
    x: m.offsetx(),
    y: m.offsety(),
    width: m.width(),
    height: m.height()
});

img.setCoordinates(0, 0);
```

**Update**

> It seems if i use JSON.stringify( arr of MyImage ) it will not work when loaded back in.

That's because JSON serializes *data*, not methods or functions. If you want to restore an array of `MyImage` objects, you should do this:

```
var images = JSON.parse(data).map(function(image) {
    return new MyImage(image);
});
```

The anonymous function maps the parsed data into a `MyImage` object and this is applied to each element of the resurrected array.

Comment: This maybe correct by i can;t store that object, becouse when I reload it its just an regular Object(); Also do the .setCoordinates function attach to each object when stored?

Comment: @Jessica I'm not sure what you mean. Could you elaborate on how you store objects?

Comment: what do you mean "it is just a regular Object()"?  have you tried this code? it's a good solution.

Comment: @Jack It seems if i use JSON.stringify( arr of MyImage ) it will not work when loaded back in ;( Anyway to store that element?

Comment: @chrisvillanueva please see above comment.

Comment: @Jessica Easy enough. Updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want to do, this will add the functions that you requested on each `img` object only when the object were instantiated/created.

```
img.prototype.setCoordinates = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

img.prototype.setDimension = function(w, h) {
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
}
```

It's a way to save some memory space. This could work.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand things, there's no way to implement `img.setCoordinates(x,y)` and `img.setDimension(w,h)` as you define. "img" is an object. Adding "img." anything will add it to the img object.  If you don't want to add internal methods to the "img" object, why don't you do this:

```
setCoordinates(img.x, img.y){ do your stuff in here}

setDimension(img.width, img.height){ do more stuff here}
```